# Spring Boot WorkManagerTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websphere

I have a Spring Boot 1.3 application which I'm attempting to deploy into WebSphere 7.

When managing threads, WebSphere only works with the Spring `WorkManagerTaskExecutor` as per thread pooling section https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/cspr_design.html

Here's the current code from the application context which I'm hoping will init the `WorkManagerTaskExecutor`:

```
@Bean
protected AsyncListenableTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    WorkManagerTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new WorkManagerTaskExecutor();
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

I've tried a variety of different methods but still run into the same exception when I run the application:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: commonj/work/WorkManager
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           at com.application.main.MyApplication.taskExecutor(MyApplication.java:156)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
>           ... 36 more

Feel like I'm missing something very simple but no clue as to what.

Comment: Have you tried setting the application classloader to use PARENT_LAST?

Comment: Where have you placed the Spring JARs and the JARs containing the `com.akqa`?  From the stack trace, it looks like classes are being loaded from URLClassLoader, which suggests you modified a JVM classpath.

Comment: At the moment this is just running via Maven Spring plugin - `spring-boot:run`